# Data from database --> to json array in .php --> this array into table in .js and then visualise it in .html by calling .js file

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, google-visualization

I have to take data from my database and show it in table in data.html + google chart. So basically my html has to call script.js file which is using read.php as API to extract the data out my database.

My html file is ok i think. But im so stuck with .js and .php files.

I need help how to store data from database into .php file and then use that data in .js file to add rows in my html table.

Please help guys.

```php
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'webuser';
$dbpass = 'secretpassword';
$dbname = 'iot_website';

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

?>


<?php

$result_set = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM sensor_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100");

?>


<?php    

$results = []; //new blank array ready for populating with row data

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
  $results[] = $res; //add the newly fetched row data into the results array
}
echo json_encode($results); //encode the array, and then echo the result so that it goes into the response for the JavaScript to read.

mysqli_free_result($result_set);
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

```js
"use strict";

google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['line'] });

document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', getData);

function addRow(data) {
    let tBody=document.getElementById("sensorData");
    let row=tBody.insertRow(-1);

    let cell=row.insertCell(-1);
    let dateTextNode=document.createTextNode(data.date);
    cell.appendChild(dateTextNode);

    cell=row.insertCell(-1);
    let temperatureTextNode=document.createTextNode(data.temperature);
    cell.appendChild(temperatureTextNode);

    cell=row.insertCell(-1);
    let pressureTextNode=document.createTextNode(data.pressure);
    cell.appendChild(pressureTextNode);

    cell=row.insertCell(-1);
    let rpmTextNode=document.createTextNode(data.rpm);
    cell.appendChild(rpmTextNode);
}

async function getData() {

    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/read1.php");
    let json = await response.json();

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'temperature');
    data.addColumn('number', 'pressure');
    data.addColumn('number', 'rpm');

    //loop through the data and add a table row and a chart row for each row received from the server
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      addRow(json[i]);
      data.addRow(Object.values(json[i]));
    }

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Sensor Data',
            subtitle: ''
        },
        width: 1045,
        height: 500
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <title>Sensor Data</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
       <header id="main-header">
        <div class="container">
          <h1><center>Sensor data</center></h1>
        </div>
       </header> 

        <section id="mainpic6">
        </section>

        <h1><center>Visualisation of sensor data --> last 100 records</center></h1>

        <div class="container">


        <section id="main4">

                <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Temperature</th>
                  <th>Pressure</th>
                  <th>RPM</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="sensorData">
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>

                    <button id="get">GET</button>

              </tbody>
            </table>

        </section>

            <div></div>

            <aside id="sidebar2">

                <div id="linechart_material"></div>

            </aside>

        </div>





        <footer id="main-footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 Arturas Website</p>
        </footer>

        <script src="script/script.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Arthur

Comment: Data in database is : id, date, temperature, pressure, rpm

Comment: Paste your code here please in your question, not in pastebin.

Comment: Anyway sounds like as an overall design you need to be using JSON and AJAX instead of outputting HTML from your PHP

Comment: Thats how it has to be done for school assignment and its already whole week that im strugling with it. read.php file = data from database  script.js file = adding rows into html table. So my html file has to call .js file and in .js i have to add rows in my html table by using .php file as API. Im so confused

Comment: probably my php code is totally wrong.

Comment: That means the PHP has to output the data in JSON format so that the JavaScript can read it and use it to create the HTML. And the easiest way to make the JavaScript fetch the data from PHP is to use an AJAX request. Those are the things you need to research.

Comment: could you not help me with code please because i have no clue what im doing

Comment: Ok, now I can see your code I think maybe you are not that far away actually. You already have some AJAX code. You just need to change the PHP code to output JSON instead of HTML. Hint: find out what JSON is (if you don't know already) and research PHP's `json_encode()` function.

Comment: Find out about that, and try to adapt your code. If you still get stuck after trying something, update the question with your new attempt and explain where you're still having trouble.

Comment: But do i still need to do query from my database? Or i have to put json_encode(result_set), result_set = the data that is stored from my querry --> array from database i assume

Comment: Yes you do. How else are you going to extract the data from the database? All you need to change is the final output format (from HTML to JSON). You still need the `while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {` loop. Within that, add each row to an array. After the loop ends, encode the array as JSON and echo the encoded string. (pretty sure you can find examples of this online already if you search...)

Comment: i have updated my php code can you take a look please? what is wrong with it now? I feel so stupid. Its just my first year of studying and i find it very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remaining issues with the PHP are:

1) You're not using your loop to create an array of rows, and instead you're trying to encode the Mysqli result set. That doesn't contain the row data directly, it has to be fetched (which is what the `while` loop is for).

2) You're still outputting HTML as well, which will confuse the JavaScript code when it tries to read your response (and assumes - as it should - that it can treat it all as JSON)

3) You're not echoing the encoded JSON - in fact you're not doing anything with it at all.

This should work better:

```
$results = []; //new blank array ready for populating with row data

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
  $results[] = array(
    "date" => $res["date"],
    "temperature" => (int) $res["temperature"],
    "pressure" => (int) $res["pressure"],
    "rpm" => (int) $res["rpm"],
  ); //add the necessary fields from the newly fetched row data into the results array
}

echo json_encode($results); //encode the array, and then echo the result so that it goes into the response for the JavaScript to read.
```

Also I don't know where you found the JavaScript, but it seems to be overcomplicating things, or is expecting a much more complex result set from the server, and it doesn't entirely make sense anyway in some places - I don't think it would work properly even with the dataset it's anticipating.

Therefore please replace the getData function with:

```
async function getData() {

    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/read.php");
    let json = await response.json();

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'temperature');
    data.addColumn('number', 'pressure');
    data.addColumn('number', 'rpm');

    //loop through the data and add a table row and a chart row for each row received from the server
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      addRow(json[i]);
      data.addRow(Object.values(json[i]));
    }

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Sensor Data',
            subtitle: ''
        },
        width: 1045,
        height: 500
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Then replace the addRow function with this version:

```
function addRow(data) {
    let tBody=document.getElementById("sensorData");
    let row=tBody.insertRow(-1);

    let cell=row.insertCell(-1);
    let dateTextNode=document.createTextNode(data.date);
    cell.appendChild(dateTextNode);

    cell=row.insertCell(-1);
    let temperatureTextNode=document.createTextNode(data.temperature);
    cell.appendChild(temperatureTextNode);

    cell=row.insertCell(-1);
    let pressureTextNode=document.createTextNode(data.pressure);
    cell.appendChild(pressureTextNode);

    cell=row.insertCell(-1);
    let rpmTextNode=document.createTextNode(data.rpm);
    cell.appendChild(rpmTextNode);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215716/discussion-on-answer-by-adyson-data-from-database-to-json-array-in-php).